# Store entire table then loop through it in the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a table of users and when the user logs in (this part I have done already) I need to pull all the entries out of the table and store them somehow, then in the view that the user is redirected to I need to loop through that stored table.

### MyDbContext Modal

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserAccount>().ToTable("User");
    }
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<WebApplication9.Models.UserAccount> Users { get; set; }
}
```

### UserAccount Modal

```
public class UserAccount
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }
}
```

### Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(UserAccount user)
{
    using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var usr = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == user.UserName && u.UserPassword = user.UserPassword);
        if (usr != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("LoggedIn");
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

My Login works just fine but I would like to save the entire user table somehow then loop through it and perform actions in my `loggedin` view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store it in a Session or TempData variable:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(UserAccount user)
{
using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext())
{
    Session["userList"] = db.Users.ToList(); 
    //or TempData["userList"] = db.Users.ToList();
    var usr = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == user.UserName && u.UserPassword = user.UserPassword);
    if (usr != null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("LoggedIn");
    }
}
return View();
}
```

To retrieve this data and to send it in view use ViewBag:

```
ViewBag.userList= Session["userList"];
// or ViewBag.userList= TempData["userList"];
```

### View

To loop through this data -

```
 @{ var userList= (List<UserAccount>)ViewBag.userList;  }
 @foreach (var item in userList)
            { 
                <p>@item.UserName</p>
                <p>@item.Password</p>
            }
```

Comment: So in my view, how can I loop through it and just display all the usernames per example

Comment: I have updated answer. ViewBag data internally passed from controller to view. Just write inside LoggedIn action.